# Pydev Remote Debug Breakpoints with QGIS Stops in _string_ instead of the python file

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, debugging, pydev

I tried to use the remote debugger with PyDev but when I reach the breakpoint, I end up in a file name "*string*" that seems to be internal commands:

[image: how breakpoints appears]

To set up the remote debuger, I followed both [PyDev Remote Debugger doc](https://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html) and [Linfinity guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20160315041546/http://linfiniti.com/2011/12/remote-debugging-qgis-python-plugins-with-pydev/) and some answers on this stack exchange.

1. Installed the First Aid Remote Debuger in QGIS
2. Installed LiClipse with PyDev
3. Create a .py script from the model provided by QGIS
4. Add the `import sys;sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files\Brainwy\LiClipse 11.0.0\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_12.0.0.202402031810\pysrc') import pydevd;pydevd.settrace()` where I wanted my breakpoint and place breakpoints
5. Start LiClipse and the debug server *before* starting QGIS
6. Connect First Aid and Liclipse
7. Open the script in QGIS and start it
8. The script stops where I asked, but I end up in *string* instead of my script

Here is the script I test:

```py
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessing,
                       QgsFeatureSink,
                       QgsProcessingException,
                       QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink)
from qgis import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing

class SequenceGetter(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    """
    This is an example algorithm that takes a vector layer and
    creates a new identical one.

    It is meant to be used as an example of how to create your own
    algorithms and explain methods and variables used to do it. An
    algorithm like this will be available in all elements, and there
    is not need for additional work.

    All Processing algorithms should extend the QgsProcessingAlgorithm
    class.
    """

    # Constants used to refer to parameters and outputs. They will be
    # used when calling the algorithm from another algorithm, or when
    # calling from the QGIS console.

    INPUT = 'INPUT'
    OUTPUT = 'OUTPUT'

    def tr(self, string):
        """
        Returns a translatable string with the self.tr() function.
        """
        return QCoreApplication.translate('Processing', string)

    def createInstance(self):
        return SequenceGetter()

    def name(self):
        """
        Returns the algorithm name, used for identifying the algorithm. This
        string should be fixed for the algorithm, and must not be localised.
        The name should be unique within each provider. Names should contain
        lowercase alphanumeric characters only and no spaces or other
        formatting characters.
        """
        return 'myscript'

    def displayName(self):
        """
        Returns the translated algorithm name, which should be used for any
        user-visible display of the algorithm name.
        """
        return self.tr('My Script')

    def group(self):
        """
        Returns the name of the group this algorithm belongs to. This string
        should be localised.
        """
        return self.tr('Example scripts')

    def groupId(self):
        """
        Returns the unique ID of the group this algorithm belongs to. This
        string should be fixed for the algorithm, and must not be localised.
        The group id should be unique within each provider. Group id should
        contain lowercase alphanumeric characters only and no spaces or other
        formatting characters.
        """
        return 'examplescripts'

    def shortHelpString(self):
        """
        Returns a localised short helper string for the algorithm. This string
        should provide a basic description about what the algorithm does and the
        parameters and outputs associated with it..
        """
        return self.tr("Example algorithm short description")

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        """
        Here we define the inputs and output of the algorithm, along
        with some other properties.
        """

        # We add the input vector features source. It can have any kind of
        # geometry.
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                self.INPUT,
                self.tr('Input layer'),
                [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry]
            )
        )

        # We add a feature sink in which to store our processed features (this
        # usually takes the form of a newly created vector layer when the
        # algorithm is run in QGIS).
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink(
                self.OUTPUT,
                self.tr('Output layer')
            )
        )

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        """
        Here is where the processing itself takes place.
        """
        # Retrieve the feature source and sink. The 'dest_id' variable is used
        # to uniquely identify the feature sink, and must be included in the
        # dictionary returned by the processAlgorithm function.
        source = self.parameterAsSource(
            parameters,
            self.INPUT,
            context
        )

        # If source was not found, throw an exception to indicate that the algorithm
        # encountered a fatal error. The exception text can be any string, but in this
        # case we use the pre-built invalidSourceError method to return a standard
        # helper text for when a source cannot be evaluated
        if source is None:
            raise QgsProcessingException(self.invalidSourceError(parameters, self.INPUT))
        (sink, dest_id) = self.parameterAsSink(
            parameters,
            self.OUTPUT,
            context,
            source.fields(),
            source.wkbType(),
            source.sourceCrs()
        )

        # Send some information to the user
        feedback.pushInfo(f'CRS is {source.sourceCrs().authid()}')

        # If sink was not created, throw an exception to indicate that the algorithm
        # encountered a fatal error. The exception text can be any string, but in this
        # case we use the pre-built invalidSinkError method to return a standard
        # helper text for when a sink cannot be evaluated
        if sink is None:
            raise QgsProcessingException(self.invalidSinkError(parameters, self.OUTPUT))

        # Compute the number of steps to display within the progress bar and
        # get features from source
        total = 100.0 / source.featureCount() if source.featureCount() else 0
        features = source.getFeatures()
        import sys;sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files\Brainwy\LiClipse 11.0.0\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_12.0.0.202402031810\pysrc')
        import pydevd;pydevd.settrace()
        for current, feature in enumerate(features):
            # Stop the algorithm if cancel button has been clicked
            if feedback.isCanceled():
                break
            # Add a feature in the sink
            sink.addFeature(feature, QgsFeatureSink.FastInsert)

            # Update the progress bar
            feedback.setProgress(int(current * total))

        # To run another Processing algorithm as part of this algorithm, you can use
        # processing.run(...). Make sure you pass the current context and feedback
        # to processing.run to ensure that all temporary layer outputs are available
        # to the executed algorithm, and that the executed algorithm can send feedback
        # reports to the user (and correctly handle cancellation and progress reports!)
        if False:
            buffered_layer = processing.run("native:buffer", {
                'INPUT': dest_id,
                'DISTANCE': 1.5,
                'SEGMENTS': 5,
                'END_CAP_STYLE': 0,
                'JOIN_STYLE': 0,
                'MITER_LIMIT': 2,
                'DISSOLVE': False,
                'OUTPUT': 'memory:'
            }, context=context, feedback=feedback)['OUTPUT']

        # Return the results of the algorithm. In this case our only result is
        # the feature sink which contains the processed features, but some
        # algorithms may return multiple feature sinks, calculated numeric
        # statistics, etc. These should all be included in the returned
        # dictionary, with keys matching the feature corresponding parameter
        # or output names.
        return {self.OUTPUT: dest_id}
```

I also tried to add pydev as import in the header, using the sys.settrace()

If I place a pydev.settrace() in the header (before the class), I get a break point in a .py file for import, but then ends up in *string* again.

Is there a step or a principle that I'm missing?

How can I have a break in the script file like [in the examples](https://www.pydev.org/images/debugger/remotedebugger3.png)?